# Methods for constructor functions

Tags: javascript

Whats the difference to add a method to a constrctor function with `prototype` or to have it inside a constructor functions like the code below? Are both considered to be OOP?

```
//Constructor function
function Box(in) {
this.name = in;
}

// Method for constructor function Box
Box.prototype.showName = function() {
return this.name;
}
```

or

```
// Constructor function with method inside
function Circle(in) {
this.something = in;
{
// Method
this.showName = function();
return this.something;
}
}
```